# Is it possible to center text in a button?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, canvas, text, center

```
User_button=Button(root,text = "User", anchor = W)              
User_button.configure(width = 50,height = 8, bg = "black", fg = "blue", border = 10 )           
User_button = canvas.create_window(42, 150, anchor=NW, window=User_button)
```

This is my code for my button - I want the text User to be in the middle of the button (the button has to be big so the text looks a bit weird sticking to one side). Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text on buttons should be centered by default. In the code you posted you're explicitly forcing it to be left-justified with `anchor = W`. Just remove the setting of `anchor` or set it to "center" (or the constant `CENTER`, which is set to the string "center").